# Angular 2 Final Release Router Unit Test

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-routing, angular2-testing

How do I unit test routers in Angular version 2.0.0 with karma and jasmine?

Here's what my old unit test looks like in version 2.0.0-beta.14

```js
import {
  it,
  inject,
  injectAsync,
  beforeEach,
  beforeEachProviders,
  TestComponentBuilder
} from 'angular2/testing';

import { RootRouter } from 'angular2/src/router/router';
import { Location, RouteParams, Router, RouteRegistry, ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT } from 'angular2/router';
import { SpyLocation } from 'angular2/src/mock/location_mock';
import { provide } from 'angular2/core';

import { App } from './app';

describe('Router', () => {

  let location, router;

  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    RouteRegistry,
    provide(Location, {useClass: SpyLocation}),
    provide(Router, {useClass: RootRouter}),
    provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: App})
  ]);

  beforeEach(inject([Router, Location], (_router, _location) => {
    router = _router;
    location = _location;
  }));

  it('Should be able to navigate to Home', done => {
    router.navigate(['Home']).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('');
      done();
    }).catch(e => done.fail(e));
  });

});
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

For testing we now create a testing module using [`TestBed`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/TestBed-class.html). We can use the `TestBed#configureTestingModule` and pass a metadata object to it the same way we would pass to `@NgModule`

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ /* modules to import */ ],
    providers: [ /* add providers */ ],
    declarations: [ /* components, directives, and pipes */ ]
  });
});
```

For routing, instead of using the normal `RouterModule`, we would instead use [`RouterTestingModule`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/testing/index/RouterTestingModule-class.html). This sets up the `Router` and `Location`, so you don't need to yourself. You can also pass routes to it, by calling `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(Routes)`

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
      { path: 'home', component: DummyComponent }
    ])
  ]
})
```

To get the `Location` and `Router` in the test, the same thing works, as in your example.

```
let router, location;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed...
});

beforeEach(inject([Router, Location], (_router: Router, _location: Location) => {
  router = _router;
  location = _location;
}));
```

You could also inject into each test as necessary

```
it('should go home',
    async(inject([Router, Location], (router: Router, location: Location) => {
})));
```

The `async` above is used like `done` except we don't need to explicitly call `done`. Angular will actually do that for us after all asynchronous tasks are complete.

Another way to get the providers is from the test bed.

```
let location, router;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
      { path: 'home', component: DummyComponent }
    ])],
  });
  let injector = getTestBed();
  location = injector.get(Location);
  router = injector.get(Router);
});
```

Here's a complete test, refactoring your example

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { fakeAsync, async, inject, TestBed, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
class RoutingComponent { }

@Component({
  template: ''
})
class DummyComponent { }

describe('component: RoutingComponent', () => {
  let location, router;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
        { path: 'home', component: DummyComponent }
      ])],
      declarations: [RoutingComponent, DummyComponent]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([Router, Location], (_router: Router, _location: Location) => {
    location = _location;
    router = _router;
  }));

  it('should go home', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RoutingComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    router.navigate(['/home']).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/home');
      console.log('after expect');
    });
  }));
});
```

### UPDATE

Also, if you want to simply mock the router, which actually might be the better way to go in a unit test, you could simply do

```
let routerStub;

beforeEach(() => {
  routerStub = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
  };
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [ { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub } ],
  });
});
```

And in your tests, all you want to do is test that the stub is called with the correct argument, when the component interacts with it

```
expect(routerStub.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/route']);
```

Unless you actually want to test some routing, this is probably the preferred way to go. No need to set up any routing. In a unit test, if you are using real routing, you're involving unnecessary side effects that could affect what you are really trying to test, which is just the behavior of the component. And the behavior of the component is to simply call the `navigate` method. It doesn't need to test that the router works. Angular already guarantees that.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer. Can you explain what the DummyComponent and RoutingComponent are used for?

Comment: From what I was able to test, the router wouldn't work by itself without some configured routes. So I configured a root class and a single route that goes to the dummy component. The dummy comonent's path is `home`

Comment: The [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/testing/index/RouterTestingModule-class.html) incorrectly use `modules` instead of `imports` in the configuration object passed to `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

Comment: syntax errors corrected: `{ provide: Router, useValue: routerStub}`, `expect (routerStub.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith (['/route']);`

Comment: Please note, with angular2 version 2.4.9, you need to have `routerState` in the mock: `routerStub = { navigate: ..., routerState: {} }`, otherwise you'll get an error. Also, when mocking with `useFactory`, one must write it like this: `useFactory: function() { ... }`, not `useFactory: () => { ... }`, otherwise another error occurs.

Comment: Just want to add that the navigate().then promise is important as otherwise the test runs too fast and other tests start throwing.

Comment: Paul - will your answer work on Angular6? I tried the approach but `location.path()` is not defined in my set up. Could you please take a look a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823091/unable-to-test-routing-using-routertestingmodule

Comment: don't bother Paul. Just solved it. It seems a different definition of `Location` was being picked. The code worked when I added `import {Location} from "@angular/common";`

Comment: When I do this, it says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined

Comment: Yes, check this (https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app/blob/master/src/app/app.component.spec.ts) and this (https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app/blob/master/src/app/modules/heroes/pages/heroes-list-page/heroes-list-page.component.spec.ts)

Comment: @ismaestro did manage to resolve that issue with TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `useValue` for `routerStub`, you can use `useClass` in the `providers` and it really worked for me.

```
export class RouterStub {
  public url: string = '/';
  constructor() { }
    enter code here
  navigateByUrl(url: any) {
    this.url = url;
  }
}
```

And in the `beforeEach` just instantiate the `routerStub` object like

```
routerStub = new RouterStub()
```

And in the test cases

```
component.router.navigateByUrl('/test');
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Good approach suggested by **Paul**
I have also configure my routing same way but additionally I have added service to update some data for routing and then check for current location.

so you can add service to update data on component which render some data and then will check about navigation.

configure below in TestBed.configureTestingModule

```
providers : [MyService]
```

then create get service in foreach

```
myService= TestBed.get(MyService);
```

update some data from service like

```
myService.someMethodCall();
```

This way you can play after some data rendering happen.