# Angular test error: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined at new RouterLinkWithHref

Tags: angular, jasmine, tdd

I don't get what I'm doing wrong, I didn't find any link of **RouterLinkWithHref** to any error in tests, furthermore I'm not using RouterLinkWithHref anywhere, as far as I know :/

Can anyone help me with this:

```
fdescribe('AddItemComponent: ', () => {
  let cmp: AddItemComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddItemComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;

  const mockRouter = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
  };
  const mockCustomCardService = {
    getItemDeliveryDate: () => Observable.empty(),
    emitItemChanges: () => Observable.empty(),
  };
  const mockActivatedRoute = { snapshot: {} };
  const mockPageDataService = {};
  const mockUserService = {};

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AddItemComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, SharedModule, TranslateModule.forRoot(), RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        SpinningService,
        FormBuilder,
        TranslateService,
        { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter },
        { provide: CustomItemService, useValue: mockCustomItemService },
        { provide: PageDataService, useValue: mockPageDataService },
        { provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute }
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddItemComponent);
    cmp = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Simple test', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Comment: I ran into the same thing with a component where I was mocking `router` like you are doing here and where I had an `<a>` tag with the routerLink attribute in the markup. Check out `RouterTestingModule`. This might be helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187305/4530745

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm currently running into the same problem..

Comment: No, I didn't, sorry.

Answer (score 20):

You should remove your routing mocks (**mockRouter**, **mockActivatedRoute**) since you already import **RouterTestingModule**, something like this:

```
describe('AddItemComponent: ', () => {
  let cmp: AddItemComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddItemComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;

  const mockCustomCardService = {
    getItemDeliveryDate: () => Observable.empty(),
    emitItemChanges: () => Observable.empty(),
  };
  const mockPageDataService = {};
  const mockUserService = {};

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AddItemComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, SharedModule, TranslateModule.forRoot(), RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        SpinningService,
        FormBuilder,
        TranslateService,
        { provide: CustomItemService, useValue: mockCustomItemService },
        { provide: PageDataService, useValue: mockPageDataService },
        { provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService }
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddItemComponent);
    cmp = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Simple test', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @sunsay!! Removing Router from providers worked for me!!

Comment: Thank you @sunsay