# Cannot match any routes. Error in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I made a simple `app` which is running correctly.

Now I am trying to write test cases of that application, so I tried with `routing`.

## [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-tnwj4b?file=app%2Frouting.spec.ts)

My routing code is this

**Main module:**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/users', pathMatch: 'full' },

];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)

  ],
```

**Feature module:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'users', component: ListingComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [ListingComponent]
})
```

**Code**

I try to run my `spec` but I am getting above error

```
describe('Initial navigation', () => {
    it('default route redirects to home (async)', fakeAsync(() => {
      router.initialNavigation(); // triggers default
      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick();
      console.log('==================');
      console.log(location.path());
      // fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/users');
      // })
    }));
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `RouterTestingModule`? https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule This post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791773/angular-2-unit-testing-with-router

Comment: yes i used tis nodule

Answer (score 0):

If you import `UserModule` to the spec, this resolves the error. As `AppModule` modules imports `UserModule` to register user feature/module routes, it must also be imported in the spec to ensure it's route registrations are available in the spec as well.

The need for this is implied at a basic level in the documentation [Testing: Import a feature module](https://angular.io/guide/testing#import-a-feature-module).

```
//setup
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      UserModule, // import module
      RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)],
    declarations: [
      TestComponent,
    ]
  });
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  router = TestBed.get(Router);
  location = TestBed.get(Location);
});
```

Here is an updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-fb8z1r?file=app/routing.spec.ts) demonstrating the functionality (test passing with no error).