# this.ProductDataService.getAllProducts is not a function using jasmine-karma

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am running unit test-cases i.e. jasmine-karma in angular7. And I am getting this error -

> ProjectManagementComponent should use the ProjectList from the service
>
> TypeError: this.ProjectManagementService.getProject is not a function

If instead of useValue , i use useClass , i get error -

> [object ErrorEvent] thrown

I tried varied options , but unable to figure out over internet.

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('ProjectManagementComponent', () => {
  let comp: ProjectManagementComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProjectManagementComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ProjectManagementComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule, RouterModule, NgbModule, NgxPaginationModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserModule,],
      providers: [{ provide: ProjectManagementService, useClass: ProjectManagementService },
               {provide: ProductsService, useClass: ProductsService}]
    })
      .compileComponents().then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProjectManagementComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
       de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form[id=addProjectCreationData]'))
        el =de.nativeElement;
      });
  }));


it("should use the ProjectList from the service", () => {
    console.log("Create a Project Service")
    const projectService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ProjectManagementService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(projectService.getProject()).toEqual(comp.getResponse);
  });
});
```

**app.component.service.stub.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { config } from "config";
const baseUrl: string = config.url;


@Injectable()
export class ProjectManagementServiceStub {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
              
    getProject(url) :Observable<any>{
        
        return this.http.get(url )
            .pipe(map(Response => Response))
                
    }

}
```

Comment: I cant see `getProject()` in your component code, when is it being called ?

Comment: Also, you dont need `const projectService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ProjectManagementService);` when you are using `useClass`

Comment: Thanks . Please check this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690695/expected-response-with-status-null-null-for-url-null-to-equal-project11

Comment: @Shashank. I corrected my code. I put the right service to call getProject().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your `providers` section, as you are not using `stub` ( **ProjectManagementServiceStub** ) which you have created

```
 providers: [{ provide: ProjectManagementService, useClass: ProjectManagementServiceStub },
             {provide: ProductsService, useClass: ProductsService}] // <--- FIX  this as well, you need to inject "stub"
```

On side note: below `it` block doesn't seem to be make sense.

```
it("should use the ProjectList from the service", () => {
    console.log("Create a Project Service")
    const projectService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ProjectManagementService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(projectService.getProject()).toEqual(comp.getResponse);
  });
});
```

This is missing the essence of unit testing as you are testing `projectService.getProject()` which belongs to `service` and **not** this `component`

Comment: I get this error -  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ProjectManagementComponent -> ProjectManagementServiceStub]: 
            NullInjectorError: No provider for ProjectManagementServiceStub!
        Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ProjectManagementComponent -> ProjectManagementServiceStub]:

Comment: @Techdive : Please remove `@Injectable()` from the  `export class ProjectManagementServiceStub`