# Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule' in jasmine-karma

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am doing unit testing using jasmine-karma. 
configuration -

```
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.22",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
```

I am getting the same error for all the test cases.

> Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'

**app.component.spec.ts**

```js
    describe('SignupComponent', () => {
            let component: SignupComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<SignupComponent>;
        let de: DebugElement;
        let username: DebugElement;
        let firstName: DebugElement;
        let lastName: DebugElement;
        let mobileNumber: DebugElement;
        let email: DebugElement;
        let password: DebugElement;
        let confirmPassword: DebugElement;
        let router: Router;
        beforeEach(async () => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [SignupComponent],
                imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule,   RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
                ]),FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserModule, ,ToastrModule],
                providers: [

                { provide: SignupService, useClass: SignupService },
                { provide: ToastrService, useClass: ToastrService },
            ]
            }).compileComponents().then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignupComponent);
                component = fixture.componentInstance;
                de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form'));
                router = TestBed.get(Router)
                username = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[id=username]'));
                firstName = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[id=firstName]'));
                lastName = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[id=lastName]'));
                mobileNumber = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[id=mobileNumber]'));
                email = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[id=email]'));
                password = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[id=password]'));
                confirmPassword = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[id=confirmPassword]'));
            });
        });
        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignupComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });
        it('Defining SignupComponent component', () => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignupComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            fixture.detectChanges();
            expect(component).toBeDefined();
        })
        it('should create component', () => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignupComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            fixture.detectChanges();
            expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        });
        it('SignUp form is inValid when empty', () => {
            expect(component.addRegisterData.invalid).toBeTruthy();
        });
        }));
```

**service.stub.ts**

```js
    export class SignupStubService {
        constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
        register(value):Observable<any>  {
            console.log("in service.ts")
            return this.http.post(baseUrl + "user/register", value)
            .pipe(map(Response => Response))

        }
    }
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
    export class SignupComponent {

      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router,
         public toastr: ToastrService, public signupservice: SignupService, ) {}
    ngOninit()
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This sort of error typically happens when you are not setting up your `TestBed` correctly.

And looking at your code, you have an extra comma after `BrowserModule`. Remove that and see if it works. If this isn't the problem, then take a good look at how you've set up `TestBed` and see if there are any inconsistencies.

Comment: @ Andrew... thanks ! But i am unable to recognize the inconsistencies. Can you help

Comment: I can't tell you what it is since you haven't included all of the code. Just make sure to remove that extra comma. And then check to make sure that each one of your references in the TestBed belong to a valid angular entity.