# As i am trying to perform unit testing on angular application..but i am getting below error while running the test

Tags: angular6, karma-jasmine

1 spec, 1 failure
Spec List | Failures
OverviewComponent should create
Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:215:1)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:10807:1)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:10700:1)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:10922:1)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:10931:1)
at http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:10869:1
at Array.forEach ()
at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:10829:1)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:10548:1)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:22567:1)

============================================

```
describe('OverviewComponent', () => {
  let component: OverviewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OverviewComponent>;
  let router : Router

 
  const fakeActivatedRoute = {
    snapshot: { data: {  } }
  } as ActivatedRoute;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[
        SharedModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
       
       // RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
       
      declarations: [ OverviewComponent,
      FooterComponent,
      LoginComponent,
      ChangePasswordComponent,
      ForgotPasswordComponent,
      AppComponent],

      providers:[
      HttpClient,
      HttpHandler,
      DataService,
      NgxSpinnerService,
      Router,
      RouterModule,
      EmitterService,
      {provide: ActivatedRoute, 
        useValue: fakeActivatedRoute}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OverviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    
  });


  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

 
});
```

Comment: Please provide code of  `should create` test for OverviewComponent. It seems that you are not providing Router

Comment: Please  have a look on code

Comment: @RazorB : your component code also. how can we know unit test behavior if we dont know the component :)

Answer (score 1):

You need create mock to Service Router.

You can also just use the RouterTestingModule and just spyOn the navigate function like this...

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { MyModule } from './my-module';
import { MyComponent } from './my-component';

describe('something', () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LandingComponent>;
    let router: Router;

    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                MyModule,
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
            ],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        router = TestBed.get(Router);

    });

    it('should navigate', () => {
        const component = fixture.componentInstance;
        const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');

        component.goSomewhere();
        expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/expectedUrl']);
    });
});
```

Font: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791773/angular-2-4-6-7-unit-testing-with-router)