# How to mock router in angular jasmine spec

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, specs

I am new to writing test specs using jasmine. I have a condition in ngOnInit() something like, router.url.includes(some string). The default spec test case which checks component to be truthy is getting failed saying TypeError: Cannot find includes of undefined. Is there any way to spy or mock includes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39793256/7365461 You can mock the router or try using RouterTestingModule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RouterTestingModule` to mock the angular router.

Just import the angular router as below.

```js
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
```

And add it to the `imports` array of `NgModule`

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
        someComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
    ],
    providers: [someProvider],
}).compileComponents
```

Then you can inject the Router as follows and use it for testing

```js
it('should Navigate', () => {
    const actiavtedRoute = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
    const router = TestBed.inject(Router);
})
```

Comment: how to fake model and pass it to next router?